# zend -mysql using the value of one field value to another field name

Tags: mysql, zend-framework, row

Assuming that I have a table

```
  emp_id              Date         total
   1                    1             10    
   1                    3             25
   2                    2             20
   3                    2             15
   3                    3             25
```

My result should looks

```
  id       1        2               3

  1       10        0              25
  2       20        0              0
  3        0       15              25
```

How can I execute this query in Zend Framework by using Zend_Db_Table or Zend_Db_Select? Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the general approach:

```
$select =  $this->getadapter()->select();
//not required with a DbTable model to provide the adapter
$select->from('Table');
$select->where('column = ?', 'value');//if required
$select->group('date');
$this->getAdapter()->fetchAll($select);
```

Comment: its amazing Rocky , really usefull